# Code Map Missing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-map

We just switched over to VS 2013 and I heard that you're supposed to be able to
generate code maps for your entire application. Awesome feature indeed, that could
get new developers on our project up to speed.

Watched a couple of tutorials, but when I tried to just right click on a method
in the application, the 'Show on Code Map' context menu is missing. In fact, I
can't find anything in VS that has anything to do with Code Maps.

My version:
Visual Studio Premium 2013

I tried installing Modeling SDK for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, but that didn't do anything.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: still relevant for VS2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Visual Studio ULTIMATE to create Code Maps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj739835.aspx

Comment: Totally missed that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Can't we create code maps and live dependency in visual studio professional 2017 - 15.9.17 ?

Answer (score 1):

This has changed [for Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/):

- The Enterprise Edition allows creating code maps.
- The Community and Professional Editions can open diagrams generated in other Visual Studio editions in read-only mode.

Comment: Can't we create code maps and live dependency in visual studio professional 2017 - 15.9.17 ?